# Open a View OnClick/OnTap of an Image in a Grid Swift

Tags: ios, swift, onclick, grid, video-player

In an app that I am designing, I have a grid and I am trying to add onclick functionality that will cause a new view to open up with an embedded external video and a text description underneath. How would I add the onclick functionality? Also, in my grid with the code that I currently have, the text is on the right side of the images. How would I move the text to underneath the image? Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI



@available(iOS 14.0, *)

struct Content: View {

    var content = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "hamster", "parrot", "ferret"]

    let columns = [ GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {

            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {

                ForEach(content, id: \.self) { content in

                   Image(systemName: "keyboard")

                    .padding()

                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)

                    Text("\(content)")

                }

            }

        }

    }

}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {

            Content()

        } else {

            // Fallback on earlier versions

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to open? If a `NavigationLink` use the `Image` as the `label` if you want to open a `sheet` use the `Image` as a `label` for a `Button` that triggers a `Bool` or a `selectedItem` variable. Too many possible solutions. Add an `onTapGesture` to the `Image`, etc.

Comment: @loremipsum How would I implement the onTapGesture to handle each image/case in a LazyVGrid? Would I need an onTapGesture for each image individually like onTapGesture dog, onTapGesture cat, etc. Would I put it in the ForEach?

Comment: Each image I would presume since each image would represent a different link. Hopefully you have a pattern for the video like www.myvideos.com/“animal name”.mp4 that way you would just fill in the animal name